# jQuery.submit() form data not submitted

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery to validate form input data before form submission.

How send data after successful validation of form inputs?

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    Enter your email: 
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe!">
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        
        var formData = {
            email: $("#email").val()
            // ...
        };
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/validation/form",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            encode: true,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
        
            console.log(data);
            
            if (!data.success) {
                
                if (data.errors.email) {
                    $('#email').after('<div class="error"><p>' + data.errors.email + '</p></div>');
                }
                
                // ...
            
            } else {    
                return;
              //ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ<--- send the form after validation
            }
        })
        .fail(function (data) {

            $("form").before(
                '<div class="flash_message"><p>Could not reach server, please try again later.</p></div>'
            );
        });
        
        
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: To submit the form, use `$("form")[0].submit()` - not the `[0]` to force the DOM submit, not jquery's submit so your (jquery)submit handler won't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @freedomn-m
 , unfortunately I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: `.done(...   ...   else {  return; //^^^^ send the form` -> `else { $("form")[0].submit(); return`

Comment: Typo in my comment above:  should be:  *note* the `[0]` (not "not")

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @freedomn-m, it works fine. I'll keep reading the jquery docs to learn more.